# CSS boxes has arrows except one

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a messaging system where one user speaks to the other. I have created message boxes with the arrows. So far all the boxes has arrows except one (see pics below). Also the height is not auto adjusting to the content. Can someone take a look at my code to see what is going on?

[image]

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-7 live-chat-feed">


            <div class="chat-date"><p>Friday 12:34</p></div>
            <div class="user-post">
            <div class="chat-avatar">
            <img src="img/bitmap(3).png"
     srcset="img/bitmap(3)@2x.png 2x, 
             img/bitmap(3)@3x.png 3x"
     class="Bitmap"><p class="time-posted">12:47</p>
            </div>

            <div class="single-post-box">
                <p class="chat-content">
            Hey there! <br>
            I noticed that not only are you a football fan
            but you also go to a lot of games! What do you think about the upcoming season and who is your favorite team? Looks to me like you are a Pats fan!</p>
            </div>



            </div>





            <div class="new-live-chat">



            <div class="chat-date"><p>Saturday 22:40</p></div>

            <div id="current-user">
            <div class="user-post">
            <div class="chat-avatar">
            <img src="img/bitmap-copy.png"
     srcset="img/bitmap-copy@2x.png 2x, 
             img/bitmap-copy@3x.png 3x"
     class="Bitmap"><p class="time-posted">12:47</p>
            </div>

            <div class="single-post-box">
                <p class="chat-content">
            Wow! That’s awesome. I love football and im a beat writer for the Pats & have the luxury of catching their games!</p>
            </div>

            <div class="single-post-box">
                <p class="chat-content">
            What about you? Are you a Pats fan yourself?</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="user-post">
            <div class="chat-avatar">
            <img src="img/bitmap(3).png"
     srcset="img/bitmap(3)@2x.png 2x, 
             img/bitmap(3)@3x.png 3x"
     class="Bitmap"><p class="time-posted">12:47</p>
            </div>

            <div class="single-post-box">
                <p class="chat-content">
                Oh yeah! Brady with the SB win again this year! </p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div id="current-user">
            <div class="user-post">
            <div class="chat-avatar">
            <img src="img/bitmap-copy.png"
     srcset="img/bitmap-copy@2x.png 2x, 
             img/bitmap-copy@3x.png 3x"
     class="Bitmap"><p class="time-posted">12:47</p>
            </div>

            <div class="single-post-box">
                <p class="chat-content">
            Thats pretty cool! No idea how much of a Pats fan you were to already have season tix! I dont even have them yet!</p>
            </div>


            </div>
            </div>


            </div>
```

CSS

```
.live-chat-feed {
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-top: -310%;
    background-color: #000;

}

.new-live-chat {
    margin-top: 20%;
}

.chat-avatar {
    position: relative;
    left: -30%;
    top: 85px;
}

.chat-date,
.chat-content,
.time-posted {
     color: #8785ab;
}

.chat-date {
    position: relative;
    left: 30%;
}

.single-post-box {
    width: 729.9px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(167, 169, 197, 0.55);
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    padding: 20px;
}


#current-user .single-post-box {
    position: relative;
    left: -15%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #1ac384;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(167, 169, 197, 0.55);

}

.single-post-box::after {

    content: '';
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #fff;
    right: 97.5%;
    top: 115px;


}


#current-user .single-post-box::after {

    content: '';
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #1ac384;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0px;

}
```

Comment: The issue you have described cannot be reproduced with the code you have provided thus far. In order for someone to help you, please provide all relevant code. Thanks!

Comment: @Mers I thought there was enough code for the issue to be resolved, thus it was relevant. What more is needed?

Comment: @Mers I just added all the css relevant to the html. That should help.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. If you copy and paste your code above into codepen or Code Snippet, you'll see that only a green right arrow is showing in the upper right corner and nothing else.

But I think I see where your issue lies: you have defined two separate rule sets for `.single-post-box::after`, one of which has a greater specificity and I think that's where the issue is. One with the `#current-user .single-post-box::after` rule set is going to take precedence over the one above it (`.single-post-box::after').

You should create two separate classes for each arrow and go from there.

Comment: @Mers I just added `#current-user .single-post-box` to give that green box with the arrow. I don't know creating separate classes will work because `.single-post-box` is for the person other than the current user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use `height: inherit;` for height property. It will create a box containing the the text without any free space at the bottom. So if you have like text of 3 rows it will create a height like 20% or something, if you have 6 rows, it will create height of 40%, etc. Hope that helps.